# Topology for Hardy spaces

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open set (of the complex plane) and let $\mathcal{H}(\Omega)$ be the algebra of analytic functions on $\Omega$ endowed with the topology of compact convergence (uniform convergence on all compacts of $\Omega$). It is known that, due to the Cauchy formula, this space is complete (and therefore Fréchet; I can elaborate more this point on request). Can one provide an example of a pointwise convergent sequence $(f_n)_{n\geq 0}$ of analytic functions (i.e. in $\mathcal{H}(\Omega)$) such that the (pointwise) limit is not continuous ? And/or is there a theorem giving properties of such (pointwise) limits ?

**Added after answer** Can one provide an explicit example of a pointwise convergent sequence $(f_n)_{n\geq 0}$ of analytic functions (i.e. in $\mathcal{H}(\Omega)$) such that the (pointwise) limit is continuous but not holomorphic ?

Comment: Yes, if you take the cleft plane $\Omega=\mathbb{C}\setminus ]-\infty,0]$

Comment: What was your sequence then ? (Converging to $\sqrt{z}$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the so-called Osgood's theorem.

It says that if $\Omega$ is a domain on $\mathbb{C}$ and $(f_i)_{i \geq 0}$ is a sequence of functions in $\mathcal{H}(\Omega)$ such that $f_i(z) \rightarrow f(z)$ pointwise for all $z\in \Omega$, then $f$ must be holomorphic on some dense open subset of $\Omega$.

It is given in the first few pages of this link.

http://www.math.wustl.edu/~sk/limits.pdf

The link also gives an example where the theorem completely holds.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Example 1 in the cited paper is exactly what I wanted and, moreover, the paper provides general theorems.